# what thread safety issue does java.util.Stack or java.util.Queue has

Tags: java

If I ignore the size() inaccuracy, and assume I allocated large enough underlying Vector so that no reallocation happens, what thread safety issue does java.util.Stack or java.util.Queue has?

I cannot think of a valid/reasonable consistency argument to say they are thread unsafe.

Anybody has some insights?

Comment: What if you pop and pop simultaneously?

Comment: What if you pop, push and pop simultaneously? :P

Comment: @alfasin You should have used *what if you `push` and `push` simultaneously*.

Comment: could you guys define what `SHOULD` happen?

Comment: @QiangLi if I push two values simultaneously in different threads then one might be erased (this is sometimes called a phantom write). If I pop two values simultaneously in different threads, then I might get the same value twice (this is sometimes called a phantom read). Other types of issues can occur if a read and a write happen simultaneously (sometimes called dirty reads or dirty writes).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch `push` delegates to `addElement`, which is `synchronized`, and `pop` is `synchronized`. I don't see how you'd get any phantom behavior on straight pushes and pops with a `j.u.Stack`.

Comment: @yshavit What order do the operations complete in? Also, that synchronization works at the method level - not at the instance. So, a `peek`, `push` and `pop` could all have race conditions if the instance isn't synchronized as well.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch A `synchronized` method synchronizes on `this`, so I don't know what you mean that it doesn't work at the instance level. And the order of the operations matters in terms of, say, what the next `pop()` will return -- but not in terms of the internal integrity of the instance's data.

Comment: @QiangLi I'm not sure why you deleted the question that you just posted, but anyways: if you'll find a way to auto-generate a regex that will match the order of repeating characters, then you can do it [more efficiently](http://regexr.com/399gp)

Comment: It's been 7 years and we're waiting for the answer "A synchronized method synchronizes on this, so I don't know what you mean that it doesn't work at the instance level"

Answer (score 5):

"Thread safe" isn't an absolute attribute for a class -- what's safe or unsafe is your *usage* of the object. You can come up with unsafe ways to use a `ConcurrentHashMap`, and you can come up with thread-safe ways to use a plain `HashMap`.

When people say a class is thread-safe, they generally mean that each method is implemented in a way that's thread-safe *on its own*. In that sense, a `Stack` is thread-safe. But its interface doesn't allow for easy/safe handling of common use cases, so in that sense it's *not* very thread-safe.

For instance, if your code checks that the `Stack` is not empty, and if so, pop an element -- that's unsafe because it could be that it had one element (and thus was not empty), but someone else popped it before you got a chance to (in which case you're trying to pop an empty stack, and will get an exception).

To be more thread-safe, you really need a single method that handles that case for you. A [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) gives you that. For instance, `take()` will block until there's a value to pop, while `poll()` will instantly return back a value or `null` if there's no element to pop.

Comment: You can concoct higher-level use cases that aren't thread-safe any more for a queue as well. The term must be used in the context of one particular API.

Answer (score 4):

[Stack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html), which extends [Vector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html), has every method synchronized. This means that interactions with individual methods are thread-safe.

[Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) is an interface. The safety of use across threads is up to the individual implementations. For example, an [ArrayBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) is thread safe, but a [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) is not.

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned "Queue" is an interface. When using `LinkedList` or `Deque`, why they are not thread-safe?

Comment: The documentation on LinkedList is very clear "If multiple threads access a linked list concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally." This is because the modifications of the internal structure (managing nodes pointing to each other) is not thread safe. If multiple threads attempt to structurally modify a LinkedList concurrently, the result is indeterminate, but will almost certainly be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this method from ArrayBlockingQueue (leave any existing synchronisation aside):

```
private void insert(E x) {
    items[putIndex] = x; 
    // HERE
    putIndex = inc(putIndex);
    ++count;
    notEmpty.signal();
}
```

Let thread A progress until HERE, and let thread B take over and execute the method; then let A continue. It is easy to see that B's `E x` overwrites A's `E x`, with count being incremented by 2 and putIndex being advanced twice.

Similar HEREs can be found in other methods as well.

All data structures with memory for data and variables for bookkeeping are blatantly vulnerable to unsynced concurrent access.

Comment: ... except that `insert` is a private method that's always invoked under a lock ([source code for 1.6](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.java)), so the class is actually thread safe.

Comment: @yshavit Absolutely, but the question seemed to ask for the dangers of concurrent operation when not synchronized. - Added a clarification.

Comment: The question asked whether `Stack` and `Queue` are thread-safe. A non-thread-safe private method doesn't really address that question, since it serves a method that _is_ thread-safe. Your answer seems to imply that `ArrayBlockingQueue` has non-thread-safe behavior, which is not the case.

Comment: @yshavit That clearly wasn't my intent - I just picked up a typical method. I hope it's clear now.